# Assign one variable to other variable (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables

I'm writing a short piece of code with some calculation method, and im using temp varibles in order to perform it.

When I'm just assigning the `SELECT` statment to `@sum1` it's working, but when I'm changing it to `@sum1 += SELECT...` it return `NULL` (see picture attached)

I've already tried the following:

- tried to do some casting (although both @sum1 and activityDur are defined as INT)
- tried to assign `SELECT` statment into one variable and then assign that variable in a new variable.
- tried to find similar problems over the web (including stackoverflow)

thx.

```
SET @sum1=0
        WHILE @i <= 10
            BEGIN   
 //**** HERE IS THE PROBLEM
SET @sum1 += (SELECT activityDur FROM dbo.tmp_activityCalculation WHERE RowNum = @i)
//**** 
IF (@sum1 > 200)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @index += 1
                        SET @sum1 = 0
                    END
                INSERT INTO tmp_finalCalc (RowNum, activityID, activityDur,actDay)
                SELECT 
                    RowNum,
                    activityID,
                    activityDur,
                    @sum1
                FROM tmp_activityCalculation WHERE Rownum = @i      
                SET @i += 1
            END
```

[Execution Result of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrCIW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @sum=0
    WHILE @i <= 10!
            BEGIN   
     //**** HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            SELECT @sum1=isnull(@sum1,0)+isnull(activityDur,'0') FROM dbo.tmp_activityCalculation WHERE RowNum = @i
    //**** 
                IF (@sum1 > 200)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @index += 1
                        SET @sum1 = 0
                    END
                INSERT INTO tmp_finalCalc (RowNum, activityID, activityDur,actDay)
                SELECT 
                    RowNum,
                    activityID,
                    activityDur,
                    @sum1
                FROM tmp_activityCalculation WHERE Rownum = @i      
                SET @i += 1
            END
```

Comment: if activityDur field is null then it will return null.So use isnull and if its null add 0

Comment: Still not working - its returns NULL again... (BTW all the values of activityDur are numbers, their isnt a null values at all)

Comment: i did initialising the variable (i just didnt paste it here to save some lines, sorry if missleading you...)

Comment: Yay it works!, thank you. I guess that you just cant assign one variable in another variable (something like @a = @a + @b)...